# loaderManager recyclerview imageview viewholder content provider fails

Tags: cursor, android-recyclerview

I am new at android  and new at posting here and trying a sink in slowly but am stuck here at inflating imageViews. Below am providing code snippets from my app that i would thank you for your help

Here is my table

```
      private static final  String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE      "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID,"+KEY_PROFILEPIC+" BLOB,"+KEY_IMAGE+" BLOB)";
```

this is my viewholder class

```
     `public CityHolder(final View view) {
     super(view);
     ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);  }
     public void bindData(final Cursor cursor) {

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    this.name.setText(name);

     String CircularNetWorkImageView =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("profilePic"));
    this.CircularNetWorkImageView.setText(CircularNetWorkImageView);


}
```

`

and  then i am using recyclerview to bind to cursor.
am also using a a content Provider to both insert and then retrieve data and load by use of the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
here is how i get the data through volley json

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("city");
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObjectCity = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonObjectCity.getString("name");                   
                String profilePic = jsonObjectCity.getString("profilePic");
                String image = jsonObjectCity.getString("image");
                City city = new City();
                city.setName(name);
                city.setProfilePic(profilePic);
                city.setImage(image);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(CityDb.KEY_NAME, name);
                values.put(CityDb.KEY_PROFILEPIC, profilePic);
                values.put(CityDb.KEY_IMAGE, image);

                getContentResolver().insert(CityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley","Error");

                    }
                }
        );
    requestQueue.add(jor);

    }

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, final Bundle args) {

    String[] allColumns = new String[] {
            CityDb.KEY_ID,
            CityDb.KEY_NAME,            
            CityDb.KEY_PROFILEPIC,
            CityDb.KEY_IMAGE
    };

    return new CursorLoader(this,CityContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,allColumns, null, null, null);


}`
```

Now the String Name is displayed in my fragment but am having issue getting the image and profilePic in circularNetworkimageView to display.
 what could i be missing, please guide me